# Regex. Get the first space instead of second

Tags: php, regex

I have this text 'Amber Costa Rica' and I want to separate it in 'Amber' and 'Costa Rica'

I'm using with php

```
preg_match('/(.*) (.*)/', $details_as_text, $matches);
```

but it gives me

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'Amber Costa Rica' (length=16)
  1 => string 'Amber Costa' (length=11)
  2 => string 'Rica' (length=4)
```

I'm sure this is simple, but i've been searching without success.

Comment: You can also use this `(\w+)\s(.*)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `.*` you can use `[^ ]*?` (or `\S*?`) which specifically selects everything until there's space.

```
(\S*?)\s+(.*)
```

[**Here's a live preview**](https://regex101.com/r/eiKUAQ/1)

Which correctly matches:

[image]

Comment: @Aschab please award this answer the green tick so that your question is deemed resolved.